# Attaching an array of effects to elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, for-loop, mouseevent

I'm trying to attach all jquery ui effects to click events on images:

http://jsfiddle.net/jfv7qyff/1/

```
var effectArray = [
    'blind','bounce','clip',
    'drop','explode','fade',
    'fold','highlight',
    'puff','pulsate',
    'scale','shake',
    'slide','transfer'
];

for(i=0;i<=effectArray.length-1;i++){
    $('#effects img').eq(i).click(function(event){
        console.log(effectArray);
        console.log(i);        
        console.log(effectArray[i]);
    //    $(this).effect(effectArray[i]);
    });
}
```

The trouble is,

```
console.log(effectArray);
console.log(i);
```

both return the right values (the array and the index respectively) but:

```
console.log(effectArray[i]);
```

just returns undefined. Why is this?

Comment: I think you need to place the click outside the Loop. Demo http://jsfiddle.net/hgs6mpLc/

Comment: That's not quite it. Each picture should have a different effect. When you click the first image, it sets off all the effects at once.

Comment: I don't think you can create click events on the fly. you can have a random effect for each click Demo -- http://jsfiddle.net/v22cLdta/  -- or have a look here for random animated image grid -- http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/02/animated-responsive-image-grid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is when the event is called, i is effectArray.length.  To make sure the event retains the right index, you'll need to use a JavaScript closure:

```
for(i=0;i<=effectArray.length-1;i++) {
    $('#effects img').eq(i).click((function() { var j = i; return function(event){
        console.log(effectArray);
        console.log(j);        
        console.log(effectArray[j]);
    //    $(this).effect(effectArray[j]);
    });
    })();
}
```

I'm also using an immediate function to initialize the closure and return the function handler.

Hope this helps!

A.